# Javascript change value of html form

Tags: javascript, html, alert

I started working on a contact form using filepicker to upload files.
Now I've got that part working except for one thing.

This is the little javascript widget to upload the file:

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="------------------"
onchange="alert(event.fpfile.url)" >
```

Now the alert displays the url of the uploaded file.

My question is: How do I get this url to be set as a value in a text field?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace your onchange value of the input tag and add a span for displaying output like in following

```
<input type="filepicker" data-fp-apikey="------------------"
onchange="displayValue(event)" />
    <span id="url"></span>
```

Add a javascript function like this

```
function displayValue(event) {
 document.getElementById("url").innerHTML=event.fpfile.url; 
}
```

This will display the URL value inside the span element
Let me know if it is worked

Comment: It displayed the value, but know it needs to get in a text field, how would I do that?

Comment: A slight change to your code did the job: `document.getElementById('attachement').value=event.fpfile.url;`

Answer (score 1):

First, it is a very bad practice to put your javascript events directly on HTML tags. I would move those out in a javascript file, loaded at the bottom of the HTML page.

Now, here is your solution:

```js
var filePicker = document.getElementById( 'file-picker' ),
    fileUrl    = document.getElementById( 'file-url' );

filePicker.addEventListener( 'change', function ( e ) {
  // is fpfile a method that filepicker
  // is adding to events?
  fileUrl.value = 'hard coded string'; // e.fpfile.url;
});

var $filePicker = $( '#file-picker-jq' ),
    $fileUrl    = $( '#file-url-jq' );

$filePicker.on( 'change', function ( e ) {
  $fileUrl.val( 'hard coded url' /* e.fpfile.url */ );
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<p>Using JavaScript</p>
<input type="file" data-fp-apikey="-------" id="file-picker">
<input type="text" id="file-url">

<p>Using jQuery</p>
<input type="file" data-fp-apikey="-------" id="file-picker-jq">
<input type="text" id="file-url-jq">
```

Comment: It doesn't do the job, it's not showing anything in the text box.
Used the exact code you're giving me, and tried both js an jQuery

Comment: What is fpfile.url returning? Because if you replace e.fpfile.url by a 'string' in the code above actually works... so I have a feeling your fpfile.url just doens't return anything.

Comment: I just created a code snippet, and the code words perfectly. Your fpfile.url must not be working.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to place the url in textbox follow the below..

Slight change from my above answer

Add textbox like in below

```
<input type="text" id="url" />
```

In Javascript change like this

```
function displayValue(event) {
     document.getElementById("url").value=event.fpfile.url; 
}
```